# CSS Slot Machine Style Animation: How Can I Make It Smooth And Stop After A Certain Amount Of Time?

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I'm trying to develop a looping slot machine style animation in CSS, but I'm not sure how to make it transition smoothly.

```css
.scrollable {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  background: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.items {
  -webkit-animation: scroll 5s infinite;
  -moz-animation: scroll 5s infinite;
  -ms-animation: scroll 5s infinite;
}

.number {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 36px;
  padding-bottom: 28px;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  27.33% {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  33.33% {
    margin-top: -50px;
  }
  60.66% {
    margin-top: -50px;
  }
  66.66% {
    margin-top: -100px;
  }
  94.99% {
    margin-top: -100px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  27.33% {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  33.33% {
    margin-top: -50px;
  }
  60.66% {
    margin-top: -50px;
  }
  66.66% {
    margin-top: -100px;
  }
  94.99% {
    margin-top: -100px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  27.33% {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  33.33% {
    margin-top: -50px;
  }
  60.66% {
    margin-top: -50px;
  }
  66.66% {
    margin-top: -100px;
  }
  94.99% {
    margin-top: -100px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollable">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="number">1</div>
    <div class="number">2</div>
    <div class="number">3</div>
    <div class="number">1</div>
    <div class="number">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make it transition nicely as to appear to be an infinite loop, as opposed to jumping back to the beginning as it does now? Also how might I get the loop to stop after a certain amount of time, say 30 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but you can make infinite loop with `content` change. Also, you can stop it after certain loops using `animation-iteration-count` property. I have tried to make it work.

See the Snippet below:

```css
.scrollable {
  height: 80px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  background: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.items{
  width: 0;
  word-break: break-all;
  word-wrap:break-word;
  white-space: pre-line;
}

.items::before {
  content:"1 2 3";
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 36px;
  -webkit-animation: scroll 5s infinite;
  -moz-animation: scroll 5s infinite;
  -ms-animation: scroll 5s infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 5;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scroll {
  0% {
  content:"1 2 3";
  }
  27.33% {
  content:"1 2 3";
  }
  33.33% {
  content:"2 3 1";
  }
  60.66% {
  content:"2 3 1";
  }
  66.66% {
  content:"3 1 2";
  }
  94.99% {
  content:"3 1 2";
  }
  100% {
  content:"1 2 3";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollable">
  <div class="items">
  </div>
</div>
```